# How can one pull the (private) data of one's own Android app?

Tags: android, adb

Attempting to pull a single file using

```bash
adb pull /data/data/com.corp.appName/files/myFile.txt myFile.txt
```

fails with

```
failed to copy '/data/data/com.corp.appName/files/myFile.txt myFile.txt' to 'myFile.txt': Permission denied
```

despite that USB debugging is enabled on the device.

We can go around the problem through the archaic route

```
adb shell
run-as com.corp.appName
cat files/myFile.txt > myFile.txt
```

but this is unwieldy for more than one file.

How can I pull the directory /data/data/com.corp.appName/files to my MacBook?

Doing this either directly or through a transit in `/storage/sdcard0/myDir (from where I can continue with Android File Transfer) is fine.

**Additional Comment**

It may be that just running

```bash
adb backup  -f myFiles com.corp.appName
```

will generate the files I am looking for. In that case I am looking for a way to untar/unzip the resulting backup!

Comment: Unless the device is rooted, you simply can't do that.

Comment: I hope you're wrong, but just in case, please move your comment to be an answer. Could you add some kind of reference to back up why you think so? I would like to save all the junk files that the buggy versions of my program have saved to make sure down the road that my closer-to-release program will gracefully handle all kinds of input files.

Comment: I'm going to cite experience (20+ devices), and of course http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal tells you that Internal Storage is private to the app. If you're just collecting debug data, write it to external storage or make it `WORLD_READABLE`.

Comment: Does that mean that one could chmod the directory from world:--x to world:r-x long enough to be able to fetch the files?

Comment: I think it might be helpful to know if you are trying to copy files from an App you are responsible for, or whether this is someone elses App. If it is your App, then you can simply write the required data to an external storage medium. If it is someone elses App, you are going to require an interface of some kind (such as a ContentProvider) or root.

Comment: It is indeed my app. It is still midway through development. To write, I opened the files using 'context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput( myFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE )'. But I can now see that this is a bad idea, and perhaps that is why so many apps store their files at the root of the filesystem rather than in the directory officially sanctioned by Android.

Comment: What I meant is don't use MODE_PRIVATE, but rather MODE_WORLD_READABLE, during development. Or better yet, use external storage during development.

Comment: @Knossos Notwithstanding that it's my app, is it not legitimate for users to be able to save a copy of the private data that an app has stored on their devices? After all, the data presumably belong to the device owner, not the app author.

Comment: The problem is how do you differentiate between the owner, and a malicious App/program, trying to interface with your Apps private data. (which could have a users personal data in)

Comment: I have written a bash script for syncing your app's files https://gist.github.com/peterchaula/fedfea3f503a97d2370b5500e1593f90

Answer (score 129, accepted):

adb backup will write an Android-specific archive:

```
adb backup  -f myAndroidBackup.ab  com.corp.appName
```

This archive can be converted to tar format using:

```
dd if=myAndroidBackup.ab bs=4K iflag=skip_bytes skip=24 | openssl zlib -d > myAndroidBackup.tar
```

Reference:

http://nelenkov.blogspot.ca/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html

Search for "Update" at that link.

---

Alternatively, use [Android backup extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) to extract files from the Android backup (`.ab`) file.

Comment: `bs=24 skip=1` is much faster than `bs=1 skip=24` (on my system, 38.6 MB/s vs 1.7 MB/s) :)

Comment: http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/access-android-app-data-without-root.html very helpful article...!

Comment: Python alternative for where openssl has not been compiled with zlib: `dd if=data.ab bs=1 skip=24 | python -c "import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.write(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read()))" | tar -xvf -` (from above source)

Comment: I've never had any success with the `dd` command on my MacBook at work. Instead, I use `java -jar ./abe.jar unpack data.ab data.tar`. You can download the abe utility from http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/files/?source=navbar

Comment: Also, I noticed that I've had to force-close the app whose data I want to backup otherwise the backup is empty ! (Android 4.4.2) Which is the same effect as when the manifest shows `android:allowBackup="false"`

Comment: Even better, directly extract the files into the local directory: `dd if=myAndroidBackup.ab bs=24 skip=1 | openssl zlib -d | tar -x`

Comment: Backed up Game data with apk. Nougat Oneplus 2.

adb backup "-apk com.nekki.shadowfight" -f "c:\myapk\samsung2.ab"

Comment: I also had to use @OJFord's solution of piping to python. I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) for Bash support on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't know why we use `dd` as much as we do.  Here `tail -c+25 myAndroidBackup.ab | ...` is fine.

Comment: I got Android Backup Extractor from here to convert the ab file to tar: https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor

Answer (score 62):

I had the same problem but solved it running following:

```
$ adb shell
$ run-as {app-package-name}
$ cd /data/data/{app-package-name}
$ chmod 777 {file}
$ cp {file} /mnt/sdcard/
```

After this you can run

```
$ adb pull /mnt/sdcard/{file}
```

Comment: thanks man!
you also need to use "cp -r" to make it a recursive copy.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961621/no-such-file-or-directory-when-cp-but-not-with-ls

Answer (score 47):

Here is what worked for me:

```bash
adb -d shell "run-as com.example.test cat /data/data/com.example.test/databases/data.db" > data.db
```

I'm printing the database directly into local file.

Comment: Exactly this command caused my db file to be corrupted. But I made it to work with the following steps:
    
------ `adb shell`  
------ inside the shell run `run-as com.example.test`  
------ inside the shell run `cat ...db > /mnt/sdcard/file.db`
------ `adb pull /mnt/sdcard/file.db .`
------ end

(sorry, line breaks are not working)

Comment: @KirillOficerov it would be good if those commands can be written in one line

Comment: Great when you need 1 file. Been using this for database. Facing the case now where I need multiple files.

Comment: For some reason using `adb shell` didn't work for me, but following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36531095/2413303) and using `adb exec-out` it worked!

Comment: It returns "adb.exe: no devices found"

Comment: @UlyssesAlves what does `adb devices` show?  you connected over usb?  did you enable developer options, and usb debugging?

Answer (score 23):

On MacOSX, by combining the answers from Calaf and Ollie Ford, the following worked for me.

On the command line (be sure adb is in your path, mine was at ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb) and with your android device plugged in and in USB debugging mode, run:

```
adb backup -f backup com.mypackage.myapp
```

Your android device will ask you for permission to backup your data. Select "BACKUP MY DATA"

Wait a few moments.

The file backup will appear in the directory where you ran adb.

Now run:

```
dd if=backup bs=1 skip=24 | python -c "import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.write(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read()))" > backup.tar
```

Now you'll you have a backup.tar file you can untar like this:

```
tar xvf backup.tar
```

And see all the files stored by your application.

Comment: Your Mac version works! 
NOTE: both `adb backup` and the `dd` tar conversion steps provide no status while working and can take minutes if you have a lot of data.  Be patient!

Comment: I am getting: "zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check"   My backup is asking for a password to encrypt though.  This python method doesn't ask for password to decrypt backup. The abe.jar in the comments in above example asks for password, but I did not get all of the files after untaring using that method.

Comment: My second attempt with abe.jar on an encrypted backup worked.

Answer (score 10):

Newer versions of Android Studio include the *Device File Explorer* which I've found to be a handy GUI method of downloading files from my development Nexus 7.

You Must make sure you have enabled USB Debugging on the device

1. Click View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer or click the Device File Explorer button in the tool window bar to open the Device File Explorer.
2. Select a device from the drop down list.
3. Interact with the device content in the file explorer window. Right-click on a file or directory to create a new file or directory, save the selected file or directory to your machine, upload, delete, or synchronize. Double-click a file to open it in Android Studio.

   Android Studio saves files you open this way in a temporary directory outside of your project. If you make modifications to a file you opened using the Device File Explorer, and would like to save your changes back to the device, you must manually upload the modified version of the file to the device.

[image: file explorer]

[Full Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a Mac machine and a Samsung phone, this is what you have to do (since `run-as` [doesn't work](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37093233#c4) on Samsung and `zlib` [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29830981/4747587) on Mac)

1. Take a backup of your app's data directory
   `adb backup -f /Users/username/Desktop/data.ab com.example`
2. You will be asked for a password to encrypt in your Phone, don't enter any. Just tap on "Back up my data". See [How to take BackUp?](https://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html)
3. Once successfully backed up, you will see `data.ab` file in your Desktop. Now we need to convert this to `tar` format.
4. Use **Android Backup Extractor** for this. [Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/?source=typ_redirect) | [SourceCode](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor)
5. Download it and you will see `abe.jar` file. Add this to your PATH variable.
6. Execute this to generate the **tar** file: `java -jar abe.jar unpack /Users/username/Desktop/data.ab /Users/username/Desktop/data.tar`
7. Extract the **data.tar** file to access all the files

Comment: Followed this exactly and the `data.tar` just extracts to a `data.tar.cpgz` @henry

Comment: I've read 5 other topics articles on this thread "how to get database from my app installed on a device" and this is the only solution that is working for me. My phone is not rooted, most commands from `adb` is not working such as `run-as` `adb shell, cd \data\data ls` etc., I don't want to install Android studio (I'm using Visual Studio Xamarin), and this solution is the most painless for me.

Answer (score 6):

You may use this shell script below. It is able to pull files from app cache as well, not like the `adb backup` tool:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then 
    echo "Sorry script requires an argument for the file you want to pull."
    exit 1
fi

adb shell "run-as com.corp.appName cat '/data/data/com.corp.appNamepp/$1' > '/sdcard/$1'"
adb pull "/sdcard/$1"
adb shell "rm '/sdcard/$1'"
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
./pull.sh files/myFile.txt
./pull.sh cache/someCachedData.txt
```

Comment: The best part is when you don't give arguments and then `rm /sdcard/` substitutes, lucky it's not `-rf`.

Comment: You can just cat directly to a file on the host: "adb shell run-as com.whatever.Fnord cat /data/data/com.whatever.Fnord/databases/logging.db > /tmp/foo" (where /tmp/foo is a file on the host machine, not the android device)

Comment: TBH I don't understand the fuss about this. The (original) script would never have deleted the directory (missing -rf switch), unless it was empty. I haven't checked but even if the directory is empty then I doubt that the script deletes the directory as it's a mount point. The script looked dangerous, but it never was...

Answer (score 2):

After setting the right permissions by adding the following code:

```
File myFile = ...;
myFile.setReadable(true, false); // readable, not only for the owner
```

`adb pull` works as desired.

see [File.setReadable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadable%28boolean,%20boolean%29)

Comment: It's all right to change the permissions while debugging, but at some point near release doing so would defeat the protection offered by default (to prevent other apps from accessing/messing up with the files). Hence a way for the developer to access the files even though they are just user-readable/writable is more desirable.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on my experience with other answers, and comments in the answers. My hope is I can help someone in a similar situation.

I am doing this on **OSX** via terminal.

Previously Vinicius Avellar's answer worked great for me. I was only ever most of the time needing the database from the device from a debug application.

Today I had a use case where I needed ***multiple private files***. I ended up with two solutions that worked good for this case.

> 1. Use the accepted answer along with Someone Somewhere's OSX specific comments. Create a backup and use the 3rd party solution,
>      [sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/files/?source=navbar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/files/?source=navbar) to unpack
>      into a tar. I'll write more about my experience with this solution at the bottom of this answer. *Scroll down if
>      this is what you are looking for.*
> 2. A faster solution which I settled with. I created a script for pulling multiple files similar to Tamas' answer. I am able to do it
>      this way because my app is a debug app and I have access to run-as on
>      my device. If you don't have access to run-as this method won't work
>      for you on OSX.

Here is my script for pulling multiple private files that I'll share with you, the reader, who is also investigating this awesome question ;) :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Strict mode: http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# 
# Usage: script -f fileToPull -p packageName
# 

# This script is for pulling private files from an Android device
# using run-as. Note: not all devices have run-as access, and
# application must be a debug version for run-as to work.
# 
# If run-as is deactivated on your device use one of the
# alternative methods here:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558353/how-can-one-pull-the-private-data-of-ones-own-android-app
# 
# If you have encrypted backup files use:
# sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/files/?source=navbar 
# From comments in the accepted answer in the above SO question
# 
# If your files aren't encrypted use the accepted answer 
# ( see comments and other answers for OSX compatibility )
# 
# This script is open to expansions to allow selecting 
# device used. Currently first selected device from
# adb shell will be used.

#Check we have one connected device
adb devices -l | grep -e 'device\b' > /dev/null

if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "No device connected to adb."
    exit 1
fi

# Set filename or directory to pull from device
# Set package name we will run as
while getopts f:p: opt; do
    case $opt in
        f)
            fileToPull=$OPTARG
            ;;
        p)
            packageName=$OPTARG
            ;;
    esac
done;

# Block file arg from being blank
if [ -z "$fileToPull" ]; then
    echo "Please specify file or folder to pull with -f argument"
    exit 1
fi

# Block package name arg from being blank
if [ -z "$packageName" ]; then
    echo "Please specify package name to run as when pulling file"
    exit 1
fi

# Check package exists
adb shell pm list packages | grep "$packageName" > /dev/null
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Package name $packageName does not exist on device"
    exit 1
fi

# Check file exists and has permission with run-as
fileCheck=`adb shell "run-as $packageName ls $fileToPull"`
if [[ $fileCheck =~ "Permission denied" ]] || [[ $fileCheck =~ "No such file or directory" ]]; then
    echo "Error: $fileCheck"
    echo "With file -> $fileToPull"
    exit 1
fi

# Function to pull private file
#
# param 1 = package name
# param 2 = file to pull
# param 3 = output file
function pull_private_file () {

    mkdir -p `dirname $3`

    echo -e "\033[0;35m***" >&2
    echo -e "\033[0;36m Coping file $2 -> $3" >&2
    echo -e "\033[0;35m***\033[0m" >&2

    adb shell "run-as $1 cat $2" > $3
}

# Check if a file is a directory
# 
# param 1 = directory to check
function is_file_dir() {

    adb shell "if [ -d \"$1\" ]; then echo TRUE; fi"
}

# Check if a file is a symbolic link
# 
# param 1 = directory to check
function is_file_symlink() {

    adb shell "if [ -L \"$1\" ]; then echo TRUE; fi"
}

# recursively pull files from device connected to adb
# 
# param 1 = package name
# param 2 = file to pull
# param 3 = output file
function recurse_pull_private_files() {

    is_dir=`is_file_dir "$2"`
    is_symlink=`is_file_symlink "$2"`

    if [ -n "$is_dir" ]; then

        files=`adb shell "run-as $1 ls \"$2\""`

        # Handle the case where directory is a symbolic link
        if [ -n "$is_symlink" ]; then
            correctPath=`adb shell "run-as $1 ls -l \"$2\"" | sed 's/.*-> //' | tr -d '\r'`
            files=`adb shell "run-as $1 ls \"$correctPath\""`
        fi

        for i in $files; do

            # Android adds nasty carriage return that screws with bash vars
            # This removes it. Otherwise weird behavior happens
            fileName=`echo "$i" | tr -d '\r'` 

            nextFile="$2/$fileName"
            nextOutput="$3/$fileName"
            recurse_pull_private_files "$1" "$nextFile" "$nextOutput"
        done
    else

        pull_private_file "$1" "$2" "$3"
    fi
}

recurse_pull_private_files "$packageName" "$fileToPull" "`basename "$fileToPull"`"
```

Gist:
https://gist.github.com/davethomas11/6c88f92c6221ffe6bc26de7335107dd4

---

**Back to method 1**, decrypting a backup using [Android Backup Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/files/?source=navbar)

Here are the steps I took on my Mac, and issues I came across:

First I queued up a backup ( and set a password to encrypt my backup, my device required it ):

```
adb backup -f myAndroidBackup.ab  com.corp.appName
```

Second I downloaded just abe.jar from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/files/abe.jar/download

Next I ran:

```
java -jar ./abe.jar unpack myAndroidBackup.ab myAndroidBackup.tar
```

At this point I got an error message. Because my archive is encrypted, java gave me an error that I needed to install some security policy libraries.

- So I went to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html and downloaded the security policy jars I needed. Now in my case the install instructions told me the wrong location to put the jar files. It says that the proper location is **<java-home>/lib/security**. I put them there first and still got the error message. So I investigated and on my Mac with Java 1.8 the correct place to put them was: **<java-home>/jre/lib/security**. I made sure to backup the original policy jars, and put them there. Vola I was able to enter a password with abe.jar and decrypt to a tar file.

Lastly I just ran ( *after running previous command again* )

```
tar xvf myAndroidBackup.tar
```

Now it is important to note that if you can just run-as and cat, it is much much faster. One, you only get the files you want and not the entire application. Two, the more files ( + encryption for me ) makes it slower to transfer. So knowing to do this way is important if you don't have run-as on OSX, but the script should be first goto for a debug application.

Mind you I just wrote it today and tested it a few times, so please notify me of any bugs!

Comment: Thanks to your response with method #1 I've been able to get and explore a package backup from a debug targeted app installed on a production non rooted device, but the backup contains only the manifest file. With method #2 I downloaded all app's data, but binaries (i.e. SQLite files) are unreadable. I add a solution based on you script that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Tamas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24658841/539149), here is a one-liner for Mac OS X to fetch all of the files for app with `your.app.id` from your device and save them to (in this case) `~/Desktop/your.app.id`:

```
(
    id=your.app.id &&
    dest=~/Desktop &&
    adb shell "run-as $id cp -r /data/data/$id /sdcard" &&
    adb -d pull "/sdcard/$id" "$dest" &&
    if [ -n "$id" ]; then adb shell "rm -rf /sdcard/$id"; fi
)
```

- Exclude the `-d` to pull from emulator
- Doesn't stomp your session variables
- You can paste the whole block into Terminal.app (or remove newlines if desired)

Answer (score 1):

Starting form Dave Thomas script I've been able to write my own solution to overcome 2 problems:

1. my backup was containing only the manifest file
2. binary files got with Dave Thomas where unreadable

This is my script, that copies app data to sdcard and then pull it

```
#Check we have one connected device
adb devices -l | grep -e 'device\b' > /dev/null

if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "No device connected to adb."
    exit 1
fi

# Set filename or directory to pull from device
# Set package name we will run as
while getopts f:p: opt; do
    case $opt in
        f)
            fileToPull=$OPTARG
            ;;
        p)
            packageName=$OPTARG
            ;;
    esac
done;

# Block package name arg from being blank
if [ -z "$packageName" ]; then
    echo "Please specify package name to run as when pulling file"
    exit 1
fi

# Check package exists
adb shell pm list packages | grep "$packageName" > /dev/null
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Package name $packageName does not exist on device"
    exit 1
fi

    adb shell "run-as $packageName cp -r /data/data/$packageName/ /sdcard/$packageName"
    adb pull /sdcard/$packageName
    adb shell rm -rf /sdcard/$packageName
```

Answer (score 0):

**Backed up Game data with apk**. Nougat Oneplus 2.

```
adb backup "-apk com.nekki.shadowfight" -f "c:\myapk\samsung2.ab"
```

Comment: ```adb backup -f myapp.ab -apk com.myapp # backup on one device```
```adb restore myapp.ab                  # restore to the same or any other device```

Comment: @StevenLinn If you want to post your example you should post a new answer instead of commenting on random answers

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that one could chmod the directory from world:--x to world:r-x long enough to be able to fetch the files?

Yes, exactly. Weirdly enough, you also need the file to have the `x` bit set. (at least on Android 2.3)

`chmod 755` all the way down worked to copy a file (but you should revert permissions afterwards, if you plan to continue using the device).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it this way after rooting device with Magisk:

```
adb shell
su root
cat /data/user/0/application/databases/ > /storage/self/primary/Download/db_data.db
exit
exit
adb pull /storage/self/primary/Download/db_data.db ~/Desktop/.
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do:

```bash
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package_name>/
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong but, have you read the question properly? OP is asking for pulling the 'private' data **NOT** 'public'