# How do I view my Realm file in the Realm Browser?

Tags: java, android, realm

I've just discovered Realm and wanted to explore it in more detail so I decided to create sample application and having a mess around with it. So far so good.

However, one thing I haven't been able to work out just yet is how to view my database in the Realm Browser. How can this be done?

Comment: WANT THE EASY WAY? Skip the path-logging, adb commands, and headache. @devsmash has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705298/483520

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Currently the Realm Browser doesn't support accessing databases directly on the device, so you need to copy the database from the emulator/phone to view it. That can be done by using ADB:

`adb pull /data/data/<packagename>/files/ .`

That command will pull all Realm files created using `Realm.getInstance(new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build())` . The default database is called `default.realm`.

Note that this will only work on a emulator or if the device is rooted.

Comment: You can also log the exact path from your app with:
    Log.d("", "path: " + realm.getPath());

Comment: So Realm Browser for Mac is useless. Who uses emulator

Comment: For non-rooted devices this script works : https://gist.github.com/jk2K/a66ed67b252b880824b32dd4952d1b39

Comment: if you get error like file not found execute adb root command first before pulling realm file .

Comment: This works after using adb root but no matter what I do, the realm file says it's encrypted when using realm browssr. Yes I read about corruption and such but nothing I try is working at all. Did something change in realm?

Comment: i can open default.realm but i used this code Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("RealmProjectName")
                .build();
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
        } finally {
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }i can pull this file but failed to open in Realm Studio.Any idea.unable to find data stored in tables ?

Comment: is there any other way to pull database from non-debuggable app and non-rooted mobile?

Comment: it also works on non-rooted device if the application is debuggable

Comment: I am testing on Emulator but still my cmd shows remote object '/data/data/<packagename>/files/' does not exist

Comment: Anyone who is facing remote object doesn't exist on linux please scroll down and check @Kumar Hitesh answer.

Comment: You can just use `strings default.realm` to view the file at its location in files/default.realm.

Answer (score 105):

Now you can view Realm DB on Chrome browser using [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/), developed by Facebook. By default, Stetho allows to view Sqlite, network, sharedpreferences but with additional [plugin here](https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm) allows to view Realm as well.

After configuring your `Application` class with above libraries, while app is running and connected, open Chrome browser and navigate `chrome://inspect` to see

---

[image]

Then `Resources->Web Sql->default.realm`

---

[image]

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.uphyca:stetho_realm:0.8.0
May anyone help me with this? I am sorry, I am not a mac user, so it looks like this way is the only I can browse my database file.

Comment: Did you add url `https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo` as shown here https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm

Comment: My fault, thank you very much! I have missed this. Now it works as it should!

Comment: Does the browser updates it's content in real time? After I set it up it shows the same content each time whereas content changes. Even after app deleting-installing again I expected realm to be empty, but it still shows the same content. Any ideas?

Comment: I watch the changes of table "A" by clicking some other table, and then clicking table "A" again @AlexKost

Comment: I have large realm db that I only read from. I see the name of it under Web SQL but there are no fields / tables....is it just taking a long time to load?

Comment: @Mike6679 not sure, i tried with about 10 tables and maybe 50 rows at most. File a bug on github if you can't see

Comment: see this post if anyone has issue with seeing fields: https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/issues/45 .... I see my fields but no data....hmmm

Comment: Problem with this solution is that if you have a lot of columns it becomes compressed and there's no horizontal scroll

Comment: @AkashBisariya i havent tested with latest realm version. but did you click Resources tab? or did you enabled stetho realm plugin in application class?

Comment: a working fork is located at https://github.com/wickedev/stetho-realm. I just set it up and is working on latest realm. Here is from another discussion with updated init example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51381971

Answer (score 58):

You can also pull your file from any NON-rooted device using the ADB shell and run-as command.

You can use these commands to pull from your app's private storage a database named your_database_file_name located in the files folder:

```
adb shell "run-as package.name chmod 666 /data/data/package.name/files/your_database_file_name"

// For devices running an android version lower than Android 5.0 (Lollipop)
adb pull /data/data/package.name/files/your_database_file_name

// For devices running an Android version equal or grater
// than Android 5.0 (Lollipop)
adb exec-out run-as package.name cat files/your_database_file_name > your_database_file_name
adb shell "run-as package.name chmod 600 /data/data/package.name/files/your_database_file_name"
```

Comment: Agreed. Since we can set the application to debuggable, we can pull the file with this without root.

Comment: is there any other way to pull database from non-debuggable apk?

Comment: if that would be possible, the entire android OS would be completely unsafe, There is a chance it could be possible only on rooted devices, but I never did it

Comment: This might not work on Samsung devices due to their buggy run-as implementations.

Comment: So, we can use this to import our edited realm back to its place?
`adb exec-out run-as package.name cat files/your_database_file_name < your_database_file_name
`

Answer (score 53):

If you are lazy to get the realm database file every time with adb, you could add an export function to your android code, which send you an email with the realm database file as attachment.

Here an example:

```
public void exportDatabase() {

    // init realm
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());

    File exportRealmFile = null;
    try {
        // get or create an "export.realm" file
        exportRealmFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), "export.realm");

        // if "export.realm" already exists, delete
        exportRealmFile.delete();

        // copy current realm to "export.realm"
        realm.writeCopyTo(exportRealmFile);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    realm.close();

    // init email intent and add export.realm as attachment
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("plain/text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "YOUR MAIL");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR SUBJECT");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR TEXT");
    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(exportRealmFile);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);

    // start email intent
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "YOUR CHOOSER TITLE"));
}
```

Don't forget to add this user permission to your Android Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This is especially good if you use **Pushbullet**. Then you can push a message to your Chrome browser and it will download the file. The file can then be opened in Realm Browser

Comment: Crashing on Android 8.0

Answer (score 50):

#### For Android (No need to root your device)

To obtain a copy of any of Realm database on your device, go to **Device File Explorer** in Android Studio.

Navigate to `/data/data/your.package.name/files/`.

There you will find your *.realm files. Right click, then *Save As*. Make sure to synchronize before you save them.

Use [Realm Browser](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases) or any of [these](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest#browse-the-realm-database) to view *.realm files:

[image]

Comment: Make sure your app is set to debuggable false in order to view the data.

Comment: @AmanVerma It's USB debugging in Developer Options. USB debugging must be enabled to use Device File Explorer

Comment: Linux user's can download realm studio using https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/ and open realm file from there

Answer (score 20):

There is a workaround. You can directly access the file from the device monitor. You can access this directory only when you are using an emulator or rooted device.

In Android Studio:

***Select***

Menu *Tools* → *Android* → *Android Device Monitor* → *File Explorer* → *data* → *data* → (Your Package Name) → *files* → *db.realm

Pull this file from the device:

[image]

From Android Studio 3 canary 1, Device File Explorer has been introduced. You need to look the realm file here. Then, (select your package) → select the realm file → Right click and
save.

[image]

And open the file into the Realm Browser. You can see your data now.

Comment: Thanks. however it's doesn't work with real device.It only works with Emulator

Comment: @prathamkesarkar, that is why I have written emulator or rooted device because you cannot get access to these folders in a normal device.

Answer (score 14):

You can access the realm file directly. Here is solution that I've used.

First you can copy the realm file that is located in '/data/data/packagename/files' to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+'/FileName.realm':

```
public class FileUtil {
    public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}

Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
        File f = new File(realm.getPath());
        if (f.exists()) {
            try {
                FileUtil.copy(f, new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/default.realm"));
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
finally {
    if (realm != null)
        realm.close();
}
```

Second, use the ADB tool to pull that file like this:

> $ adb pull /sdcard/default.realm .

Now you can open the file in the Realm Browser.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that doesn't require your phone to be rooted, by making use of the `run-as` command present inside `adb`'s shell. Only pre-condition is that you must have a debug build of your app installed on the target phone.

```
$ adb shell
$ run-as com.yourcompany.yourapp # pwd will return /data/data/com.yourcompany.yourapp
$ cp files/default.realm /sdcard
$ exit
$ exit
$ adb pull /sdcard/default.realm ~/Desktop # or wherever you want to put it
```

You'll have a copy of the DB from any phone inside your local directory, which you can then load onto the Realm Browser.

Comment: mac adb default path .../Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

Answer (score 5):

For over two years now, the Realm Browser has been available for every operating system (mac, linux, windows).

https://docs.realm.io/sync/realm-studio

Works straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

You can now access it directly if you're using an emulator.

**First** Log the path where the file is in the emulator as @bmunk says:

`Log.d(TAG, "path: " + realm.getPath());`

**Second** Search it and do right click on the file and choose "Save As", on the dialog will appear the route where the file really is in your system.

[image]
[image: You can copy the route from the Save As dialog]

And then, just paste the route on the "Open Local File" dialog of Realm Studio.

(I've tested this in Windows only)

Comment: This is the most useful answer, thank you! Does not show the path for macOS, but it is still easy to locate the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my ready-to-use shell script.
Just change package name and your adb paths then the script will do the necessary.

```
#!/bin/sh
ADB_PATH="/Users/medyo/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
PACKAGE_NAME="com.mobiacube.elbotola.debug"
DB_NAME="default.realm"
DESTINATION_PATH="/Users/Medyo/Desktop/"
NOT_PRESENT="List of devices attached"
ADB_FOUND=`${ADB_PATH}/adb devices | tail -2 | head -1 | cut -f 1 | sed 's/ *$//g'`
if [[ ${ADB_FOUND} == ${NOT_PRESENT} ]]; then
    echo "Make sure a device is connected"
else
    ${ADB_PATH}/adb shell "
        run-as ${PACKAGE_NAME} cp /data/data/${PACKAGE_NAME}/files/${DB_NAME} /sdcard/
        exit
    "
    ${ADB_PATH}/adb pull "/sdcard/${DB_NAME}" "${DESTINATION_PATH}"
    echo "Database exported to ${DESTINATION_PATH}${DB_NAME}"
fi
```

More details on this blog post : http://medyo.github.io/2016/browse-populate-and-export-realm-database-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple:

```
/Users/inti/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb exec-out run-as com.mydomain.myapp cat files/default.realm > ~/Downloads/default.realm
```

Explanation:

1. Find the path to your `adb` install. If you're using Android Studio then look at File > Project Structure > SDK Location > Android SDK Location and append `platform-tools` to that path.
2. Use your app's fully qualified name for the `run-as` argument
3. Decide where you want to copy the realm file to

NB: The file is called default.realm because I haven't changed its name when configuring it - yours may be different.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options to view your android realm files:

1. Like @Christian Melchior said you can pull your realm database from device and open it on your mac using [OSX Realm Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/sk/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12)
2. You can use third party [Android Realm Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.min60.android.realmbrowser.free) I created, to make android development with realm little bit easier. App will show you all realm files on your device, and you can view all your realm files real time while testing your app.
3. You can use Chrome browser [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) Full description how to use Setho is provided by @Jemshit Iskendero answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Realm Browser** is **Deprecated**, Use **Realm Studio** instead.

## HERE

View filepath

```
console.log(realm.path)
```

Login adb as root

```
adb root
```

Pull realm file to local dir

```
adb pull /data/data/{app.identifier.com}/files/default.realm .
```

## Result view in Realm Studio

[Result view in Realm studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODqnO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shell for lazy people like me :)

The `.realm` file will be stored inside the `tmpRealm/` folder next to the `.sh` file.

```
#!/bin/sh
adb shell 'su -c "
cd /data/data/<packagename>/files
ls
rm -rf /data/local/tmp/tmpRealm/
mkdir /data/local/tmp/tmpRealm/
cp /data/data/com.arefly.sleep/files/* /data/local/tmp/tmpRealm
chown shell.shell /data/local/tmp/tmpRealm/*
"'
rm -rf ./tmpRealm/
adb pull /data/local/tmp/tmpRealm ./
```

Or if you prefer to let `tmpRealm/` be on the SD card:

```
#!/bin/sh
adb shell 'su -c "
cd /data/data/com.arefly.sleep/files
ls
mount -o rw,remount $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/
rm -rf $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/tmpRealm
mkdir $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/tmpRealm
cp /data/data/com.arefly.sleep/files/* $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/tmpRealm
"'
rm -rf ./tmpRealm/
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225750/176808
adb pull "$(adb shell 'echo "$EXTERNAL_STORAGE"' | tr -d '\r')/tmpRealm" ./
```

*Reference:*

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28486297/2603230
2. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/129665/179720