# How can I bundle a Realm database file with my app to deploy with installation

Tags: android, realm

I have a data set of around 50k records which I want to put in a Realm database. I am unsure of how can I make this DB in Realm and bundle it with the App so that the file can reside from the very start (installation) in the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a Realm file in your assets folder and copy it the first time you open the app. There is an example on how to do that here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/MigrationExampleActivity.java#L57

You can then use SharedPreferencs/another Realm or similar to save a boolean to indicate that the Realm file has been copied.

Right now we don't have any API working outside Android, but one way to create a prepopulated Database is to make a small app that does it, run that that app on an emulator and then use ADB to pull the database: [How to view my Realm file in the Realm Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478987/how-to-view-my-realm-file-in-the-realm-browser/28486297#28486297)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try.