# Where does realm store data in mobile?

Tags: android, realm

I started searching for an alternative to `SQLite`. I found realm. I understand that it is faster and safer. But I wonder where does realm store data in mobile?

1. Does it increase App's data size? like sqlite
2. Can we see the data as the app user? Like sqlite

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Does it increase App's data size? like sqlite

Yes, it increase the size.It stores data in data folder.

> 2) Can we see the data as the app user? Like sqlite

The Realm Browser is only available on Mac OS X at the moment.
We are working on Windows & Linux versions. see [**Official Site**](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-browser)

Path of realm file  on device  [**How to view my Realm file in the Realm Browser?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478987/how-to-view-my-realm-file-in-the-realm-browser)

Comment: Thanks N J. Does user of the app can access Realm browser and Realm storage? If so, they can corrupt app stored data? Isn't

Comment: No user of app can access only when device is rooted . On other side it is stored in private data folder . So if device is rooted then user can access file

Comment: Thanks. i got the answer for this question. I will open another question about user access if I still confused.

Comment: Storage occupied by realm is same as Sqlite?

Comment: I haven't gone deep in that ..:( about size comparison

Comment: @NJ any way to check realm file size programmatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Realm stores its data in the internal storage (data folder)

You can use either the Realm Browser for MAC,  or Stetho-Realm via Chrome browser to view the database