# How to view realm database tables in android using Stetho?

Tags: android, realm, stetho

How to view database tables created using realm,for testing purpose.Is there any tool avilable to view the tables?.Anyone knows the answer please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow this link: https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm and https://medyo.github.io/2016/browse-populate-and-export-realm-database-on-android/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [plugin stetho-realm](https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm) and installation of it documented in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187414/53870).

This is from a third-party, not from Realm but very much encouraged by us. We love our community.

Answer (score 4):

Updating for future people that will face the same issue:

the stetho-realm original by uPhyca is not supporting latest versions of realm (when you open at chrome, the app crashes)

So, you should install a fork working, see:

https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/issues/62#issuecomment-346927558

Thanks to @WickedDev

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me in late 2019 with nearly latest version of everything:

In your build.gradle file

```
repositories {
maven() {
        url 'https://github.com/WickeDev/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.2.2'
}
```

In your Application(java) file:

```
    Realm.init(this);

    //--- for development setting only
    Stetho.initialize(
            Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                    .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                    .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build())
                    .build());
```

Comment: It's 2021 and the `WickeDev` repo no longer exists... There is the `https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo` repo but it has an older version that does not seem to work.