# How to view, insert data to realm by software

Tags: android, database, sqlite, realm

I'm using Realm database for Android to replace SQLite. In my older app, I use Navicat to view, insert data and my app display data from database have saved in assest directory. But now, I want to replace database SQLite by Realm so how to view, insert data to realm by software like Navicat?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stetho`. You can view your `Realm Database` in your `Chrome Browser` by using `Stetho`. You can follow this [Realm module for Stetho](https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm), [Tutorial on how to browse Realm Database](https://medyo.github.io/2016/browse-populate-and-export-realm-database-on-android/) and [Guidelines for Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/). Also, see this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478987/how-to-view-my-realm-file-in-the-realm-browser/34187414#34187414).