# How to connect Android app to Realm Browser in macOS

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-browser

Our team has recently decided to try out Realm as our db solution. For easy debugging, we were hoping the Realm browser comes handy, however, there is no documentation for that.

Anyone?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478987/how-to-view-my-realm-file-in-the-realm-browser

Comment: I spoke to the engineering team at Realm, they said "we don't currently have documentation written for the Realm Browser. However, as the browser is open-source, the source code may be able to help you. You can find the GitHub repository here: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx. "

Comment: Or you can use Android app to view your realm files directly on your android device. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.min60.android.realmbrowser.free