# realm database from react native project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, react-native, realm

I've [`react native`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) project with [`realm`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java) DB from my team dev,

but I have limited information about react native structure, so I want to use `android studio` to display realm DB in `react native` project,

the problem is :

1. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28486297/8943429) just work on emulator or rooted device, and I dont have both of them
2. [`stetho`](https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm) module work at `public class MyApplication *extends Application*`,
   but in react native project I need to edit `MainApplication.java` to get **`extends Application`**

how can I access my realm in android studio while the realm module in `node_modules` outside android folder?

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/36531095/2413303 to pull the file, but Android File Explorer should also work.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but the problem i dont know the db file name also, thats why i want to use `Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` for knowing the file name also,

Comment: If you didn't specify a name, then it is called `default.realm`