# Failed to find database file from ddms folder while running app in emulator using Realm

Tags: android, database, sqlitemanager

Trying to find database file from Tools ---> Android Device Monitor but its giving me error: [image: See image for error]
While i already defined path for JAVA_HOME environment variable and path as well.
JDK is installed in path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin
But still its failed to start monitor and access db file.

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio

Comment: Have you tried restarting Windows? :P

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes tried but still failed.I am using Realm db and want to see tables and its records

Comment: If you are using Windows 8.1 or higher, you can use Realm Studio

Comment: @EpicPandaForce pls share link , the major issue is how will i pull db file from data/data folder in case of running app in emulator

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/36531095/2413303

Comment: i tried but getting this error in sqlite browser https://imgur.com/a/3CUte

Comment: i have got database file containing tables ... but unable to see contents stored in tables.How can i see this ?