# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/realm/internal/LinkView

Tags: android, realm, stetho

I am using Realm. I installed Stetho-Realm to view realm data.

This is what i have done.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        ...
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
        }
    }
}
```

**App gradle**

- stetho:1.5.0
- stetho_realm:2.1.0
- multidex:1.0.3
- multiDexEnabled true

This is gradle code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    ...

}

dependencies {
    ...
    // Stetho
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.1.0'

}
```

**My app class**

```
public class MyApp extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

        // Stetho
        Stetho.initialize(
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                        .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build())
                        .build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

But **App is *crashing* with this error** :
After Run on android studio, App was installed normally. I clicked "Inspect" in "chrome://inspect/#devices:" after the app appeared on the device. At this point, the app was crashed and shows the error. How can I see the realm db through Stetho?:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: StethoWorker-main-13
    ...
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/realm/internal/LinkView;
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getParameterTypesInternal(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:179)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1881)
        at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.MethodDispatcher.buildDispatchTable(MethodDispatcher.java:115)
        at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.MethodDispatcher.findMethodDispatcher(MethodDispatcher.java:53)
        at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.MethodDispatcher.dispatch(MethodDispatcher.java:60)
        at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.ChromeDevtoolsServer.handleRemoteRequest(ChromeDevtoolsServer.java:129)
        at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.ChromeDevtoolsServer.handleRemoteMessage(ChromeDevtoolsServer.java:111)
        at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.ChromeDevtoolsServer.onMessage(ChromeDevtoolsServer.java:87)
        at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketSession$1.handleTextFrame(WebSocketSession.java:176)
        at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketSession$1.onCompleteFrame(WebSocketSession.java:136)
        at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.ReadHandler.readLoop(ReadHandler.java:44)
        at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketSession.handle(WebSocketSession.java:45)
        at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketHandler.doUpgrade(WebSocketHandler.java:117)
        at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketHandler.java:83)
        at com.facebook.stetho.server.http.LightHttpServer.dispatchToHandler(LightHttpServer.java:84)
        at com.facebook.stetho.server.http.LightHttpServer.serve(LightHttpServer.java:61)
        at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.DevtoolsSocketHandler.onAccepted(DevtoolsSocketHandler.java:52)
        at com.facebook.stetho.server.ProtocolDetectingSocketHandler.onSecured(ProtocolDetectingSocketHandler.java:63)
        at com.facebook.stetho.server.SecureSocketHandler.onAccepted(SecureSocketHandler.java:33)
        at com.facebook.stetho.server.LazySocketHandler.onAccepted(LazySocketHandler.java:36)
        at com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer$WorkerThread.run(LocalSocketServer.java:167)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.realm.internal.LinkView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.MyApp.app-xknjnMn3NM61rqAc4Zy3uA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.MyApp.app-xknjnMn3NM61rqAc4Zy3uA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/io.MyApp.app-xknjnMn3NM61rqAc4Zy3uA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Answer (score 11):

Stetho-Realm is unmaintained and doesn't support Realm version above 3.7.1

However there is a community fork: https://github.com/wickedev/stetho-realm

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/WickeDev/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.3.0'
}
val realmInspector = RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this)
            .withDeleteIfMigrationNeeded(true)
            .build()

Stetho.initialize(Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
            .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
            .enableWebKitInspector(realmInspector)
            .build())
```

Comment: Awesome!! The results are shown. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: If it worked, you might want to accept the answer with that tick mark thing on the top left

Comment: I've had to add `.withDeleteIfMigrationNeeded(true)` otherwise the connection drops when you click on the Realm database on Chrome (says 'Connection lost')

Comment: I had to add `withDeleteIfMigrationNeeded(true)` to Stetho-Realm library because nobody else did it. :P

Comment: I can see many things (like the shared prefs) and some google database but not the realm db

Comment: Are you configuring stetho realm properly? Make sure you are using 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Realm Studio over stetho which is available for both Windows and Mac. You can simple pull the realm db file using adb command

> **adb pull** /[path to local storage]/android/data//files/[realm file]  [path of folder on your pc]

Comment: In fact, since AS 3.0, you can use the Android File Explorer and copy your file out with that.