# No such file or directory when 'cp' but not with 'ls'

Tags: android, shell, adb, ls, cp

I am trying to copy the shared preferences folder of my app to the /sdcard partition from my PC using the following ADB command:

> adb shell su -c "cp
>   /data/data/com.anrapps.pixelbatterysaver/shared_prefs/
>   /sdcard/appdata/"

But this returns `cp: Skipped dir '/data/data/com.anrapps.pixelbatterysaver/shared_prefs': No such file or directory`. However when executing the ls command, it says that folder is present:

> adb shell su -c "ls /data/data/com.anrapps.pixelbatterysaver"
>
> cache 
>   code_cache 
>   files 
>   shared_prefs

What is the problem? May be permission related?

Comment: You need to use `cp -r` to copy a directory.

Comment: @PaulTomblin True, it worked. Dont know to much about UNIX commands. Please, post as an answer and explain why and I will mark as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to copy a whole directory, you need to use `cp -r` to make it a recursive copy.